# Serializing string content

Tags: c#, .net-core, serialization

I had an ASP.net app in which we serialized a string content using BinaryFormatter like this :

```cs
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
try
{
     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
     {
         bf.Serialize(ms, Content);
         var SerializedContent = ms.GetBuffer();
         return SerializedContent;
     }
// ...
```

But now that BinaryFormatter has become obsolete I am getting exception. I have been trying to use XMLSerializer but haven't been able to make it work. This is what I have been trying:

```cs
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(Content.GetType());

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(ms, Content);
    var SerializedContent = ms.GetBuffer();
    return SerializedContent;
}
// ...
```

But I don't get the correct output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One could argue that a string is already serialized.

Comment: What's your use case? Do you need to support deserializing values that have existed for an extended period of time? I believe guidance around binary serialization has been clearly against long-term storage. Issues like versioning and endianness spring to mind.

Comment: If you serialize a string as XML the best you can hope for is to get a bigger string that includes the original string.

Comment: Which is also true of `BinaryFormatter` because it's just wrapping the string in type information.

Comment: As @ScottHannen mentioned, if you use XmlSerializer, it will create a XML string, something like this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string>YOUR_STRING_CONTENT</string>`. Thus, you will get a different output.

Comment: What is your usecase? if you want to encode your string as a byte array why not just use utf8?`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputSring)`

Comment: @musium I want to be able to store the content in db as a hex. Is it possible?

Comment: @madreflection with the old function we were storing the content in db as a hex value. Can I do the same ?

Comment: That never should've happened. Binary serialization was meant for in-process marshalling (across AppDomains) and across-the-wire communication, not long-term storage. You need to get those values out while you can and put them in as the strings that they are.

Comment: @madreflection thanks for the response, but now how do we serialize the string since the binaryFormatter class has gone obsolete

Comment: Using it is not an error, just a warning, so use it to extract the data and then find an alternative, like **storing it as a string in the database**.

Comment: A single string doesn't need to be serialized. It's already in a serial format, and databases support strings natively.

Comment: @madreflection I am pretty sure it threw an exception for me

Comment: That's a rather vague statement. What exception? What did you do? It sounds like you created an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) by trying to avoid the exception instead of fixing it.